# Kotlin NPE, variable that can't be null is null - how?

Tags: kotlin

I'm implementing a library from github and I'm getting this exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.github.sceneview.ar.ARCore.create(android.content.Context, androidx.activity.ComponentActivity, java.util.Set)' on a null object reference
     at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneView.onCreate(ARSceneView.kt:336)
     at androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(DefaultLifecycleObserverAdapter.kt:24)
     at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
     at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
     at io.github.sceneview.SceneView.<init>(SceneView.kt:495)
     at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneView.<init>(ARSceneView.kt:141)
     at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneKt$ARScene$1.invoke(ARScene.kt:211)
     at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneKt$ARScene$1.invoke(ARScene.kt:208)
```

this is where it crashes:
[image]

this is how arCore is declared:
[image]

I'm even getting this warning if I add a null check:
[image]

So what exactly is happening here? I'm trying to understand why something that can't be null is null. I don't think this problem is specific for this library but if anyone's interested: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android/blob/main/arsceneview/src/main/java/io/github/sceneview/ar/ARSceneView.kt

Comment: Can you post your entire activity ?

Comment: What version of SceneView are you using ?

Comment: This might be problematic, it's part of a bigger project built in compose. The composable function is very similar to the one in library sample app: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android/blob/main/samples/ar-model-viewer-compose/src/main/java/io/github/sceneview/sample/armodelviewer/compose/MainActivity.kt - it's basically ARScene in a Box.

SceneView 1.2.0

Comment: If a property is `open` and you access it from a constructor, it will possibly be null if it was overridden by a subclass. This is one of the reasons you should avoid ever calling an open function or property from a constructor. Note that init blocks and property initializers are part of your constructor, the way I’m using the word.